# Using previous value when calculating in loop

Tags: android, while-loop

I'm displaying a scoreboard from a SQLite table in my app.
I want to the players so that they have the position in front of there name.
The problem i am having is that if they have equal time i want them to have equal position.
and after this i want the loop to jump over the next position. All this should be calculated and inserted into the SQLite database.

```
Like this:

position   name    time
1         George   4.00
2         Bill     5.02
2         Henry    5.02
4         Sabina   6.05
5         Heini    6.32
```

I'm not shure how to tackle this.
I want the loop to run just before i set my view, because the background data is changing also.

Can I use an `cursor` to select from my database an run a while loop? and how can i refer to the previous selection?

Thanks

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-rank.html)?

Comment: @st0le great! Don't have the know how to setup this kind of query. Thanks! solved it for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int position = 1;
int time, previousTime = 0;
String name;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    name = cursor.getString(...);
    time = cursor.getInt(...);
    if (time != previousTime) {
        position = cursor.getPosition() + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(position + " " + name + " " + time);
}
```